# Attempted to load class "JWTUserFactory" from namespace "Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory"

Tags: symfony4, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have the following error in production,

> I try to load the class "JWTUserFactory" from the namespace "Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory".
>
> Forgot a "use" declaration for another namespace?

Although the same says in local does not give me failure. Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by updating the project using `composer update`